# Авто обновление чтение файла php

Tags: php, html

Подскажите пожалуйста, получаю данные из текстового фала вот таким кодом:

```html
<?php echo file_get_contents('textfile.txt') 
?>
```

После в этот txt файл заноситься новая информация, как получить новые данные из этого файла безе перезагрузке страницы?
Спасибо.

Comment: Если файл лежит на сервере: либо ajax запрос, либо перезагрузка.

Comment: @Axenow подскажите как сделать ajax запрос?

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_ajax_callback - вот тут можно посмотреть Javascript код. Ну а точное решение можно получить, только если знать, что у вас на странице и что надо обновлять.